# Incremental backup via Java

Tags: java, mysql, json, jdbc, database-backups

I have a remote database, and I need to send data in JSON format from just one table to someone from time to time.

So basically, I need to do incremental backups from just one table of database, the catch is, I **need** to implement it in java.

What I came up with is:

I get all the data from the table, parse it to JSON array and then store it into a `.json` file/ The next time I use a program, it'll take all previous json files and

1. parse them into json,
2. merge objects from these files into one json array, and
3. then (somehow) subtract identical objects of that array from new array (Full data from table, parsed to JSON array), and
4. put this program to OS scheduler.

But with time the database will grow and so will amount of these files, in some time the program will take too much memory.

Is there any other way to do incremental backup of just one table and store them in JSON files? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: My advice is to make sure that the files will actually grow to the point where you are worried about taking too much memory before you try to optimize for it. Also: if the DB is continually growing, shouldn't you create some scheduled maintenance to clean up old records that are no longer needed?

Comment: Is there some metadata included in the table to find out in what order records were inserted or updated?

Comment: @JimmyB, i'm afraid none, but i can add it.

Comment: Why via Java? MySQL already has extensive command line tools and built-in facilities for backup and replication. Adding a specific Java application only adds risk, not value.

Comment: @EJP As far as i kno, it can't back up only one table incrementally or convert backup to JSON